# OpenCLLink M1 not supported

Tags: opencllink, apple-silicon

I am currently using

- Macbook Air M1
- Wolfram Engine 13.3

`Compile`, `FunctionCompile` works with no issues, however an attempt to call

```mathematica
Needs["OpenCLLink`"] 
OpenCLQ[]

> False
```

and a message appears `platform is not supported`.

Is there any way to debug this error? According to the documentation, there is no extra requirement for the library to work. M1 supports OpenCL 1.2 and successfully runs examples from apple in XCode.

Comment: "M1 supports OpenCL 1.2 and successfully runs examples from apple in XCode." Wut? I thought Apple deprecated OpenCL altogether. Check that out first

Comment: I am running macOS Sonoma 14.1.2 and Mathematica 13.3.1 on an M1 Max. When I run your commands, it returns True.

Comment: Hm. On M1 Max, macOS 14.1.2, and Mathematica 13.2.1 I get false. Hmmm. I think I have to upgrade...

Comment: Hmm. Could be some specific Wl version + Macos combo causes the problem. I have tried to downgrade to 13.0, but not upgrade

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I still hope that they won’t drop the support of CL, since this is only framework which is crossplatform and easy to use…:)

Comment: Exactly. In one of my projects, I had to write OpenCL code for an NVidia card that ran on a Linux machine. I thought I had double checked at that time whether this was possible nor not. in the end, I wrote and debugged the code in Metal and let a doctoral student port it to OpenCL. I am still not confortable with the fact that I cannot run it on my machine. I guess now you understand my surprise when you said you can make OpenCL run on an M1... ^^

Comment: Looks like It is hard to rely on OpenCLLink, I am still struggling to debug this issue. I am already thinking to write my own one open-source and with Complex numbers support (for some reason it is absent compared to CUDA version)… In the case of success I will for sure share my solution as an answer.

Comment: @KirillVasin In my case it is even worse. Mine OpenCLQ does not print anything, neither False or True. It does not even return itself, just crashes. CUDA works just fine though, even nvcc compiler

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников, sad to head that. We definitely need something more reliable and crossplatform. There are such technologies like WebGL, or WebGPU, but no one is interested in bridging it with WL